# How to paginate an embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, micronaut, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I've a project based on a mongodb database and I need to accomplish the following description in a very optimized way. My database has a Document with another embedded documents and I need to apply pagination in this embedded documents, eg:

```
{ _id: "str", .... , emebedded_doc_example = [ {},{},{} ] }
```

The problem is that at first we didn't expect that `embedded_doc_example` will grow as much as it is. So I want to apply pagination and filtering on server side on the `embedded_doc_example`. Then I'm seeing two solutions:

1.Get all the embedded documents of a give parent's `_id` and then apply the filters and the pagination in the list.

2.Separate the `emebedded_docs_example` in another doc and create a relation to the old parent.

The problem is better for me since it doesn't requires a lot of refactoring. However, I don't know if this will improve the results a lot since I'm loading all the embedded objects of a given parent in memory. Am I right?

Comment: The optimal approach for pagination is to query the data based on a proper index, and hold the cursor open.  For each page, read the appropriate quantity of records from the cursor into a local variable for retention (Mongo cursors cannot be walked backwards).  This can be challenging because many apps are stateless. In a highly concurrent system you might have multiple cursors, and/or local variables holding data.  Several caveats  - if data is added after the original query they will not be included in the cursor.  MongoDB sessions and cursors time out.  If they time out you need to resubmit

Comment: Are you using Spring Data MongoDB in a Micronaut service?